# How use the FontAwesome icon in Laravel array_map & link_to_route fucntions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, font-awesome

I have this piece of code which displays tags assigned to my `Entity` model.

```
    {!!
        join(', ',
        array_map(function($o) {
        return link_to_route('entities.summary',
        $o->name,
        [$o->id],
        ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm']
        );},
        $o->tags->all())
        ) 
    !!}
```

### problem

I want to add FontAwesome icon. I have no clue. Any ideas? 
One solution is to dro the code and do a `foreach` loop, but I prefer to stick to the existing one.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`link_to_route` doesn't support what you want to do. It by default escapes the title so you can't inject html/fontawesome tags.

You can likely re-work a bit of your code to use the more direct `link_to()` function with manual route injection. This will allow you to escape the "title" and add your own `<span class="fa fa-icon ..."></span>` code inside the a tag via the title parameter.

This is rough, and untested, the primary change is creating your own route with the options:

```
{!!
    join(', ',
    array_map(function($o) {
        return link_to(route('entities.summary', [$o->id]), // url
        "<your fa code>" . $o->name, // title
        ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'], // attributes
        null, // secure
        false // escape
        );
        },
        $o->tags->all())
    ) 
!!}
```